# Generate commercial license key for web service

Tags: licensing, api, http, software-as-a-service

## Background

I have a business question regarding web-based software licensing. A number of web sites offer software as a service for various APIs. A good example is Google's [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). The process to use web services typically resembles:

1. **Account.** User creates an account.
2. **Server.** User defines the IP address(es) of the server(s) that will make API requests.
3. **Key.** User receives a public API key for the desired API(s).
4. **Guide.** User is given documentation that shows how to use the API key to make a request.
5. **Test.** User can make test requests to verify integration functionality.
6. **Billing.** User pays to activate the account.
7. **Production.** User integrates the web service into their applications.
8. **Deactivation.** System deactivates accounts when expired, exceeds request limit, etc.

These requirements are in addition to integration with the service being licensed.

## Problem

That is a lot of work for a small business.

## Questions

What off-the-shelf, open source projects address this problem?

If there are no such projects, what would you do to architect a viable, low-cost solution (ideally, a percentage of each license)? That is, what software or existing commercial services would you use for a small business (having little to no income) that seeks to license web-based services?

Thank you!

## Related Links

- [License key solution in web application, what is the best approach?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83633/license-key-solution-in-web-application-what-is-the-best-approach)
- [API Management System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533701/is-there-a-free-api-management-system-e-g-a-mashery-alternative)

Comment: No idea of their costs, but Mashable may be an option: http://www.mashery.com/product/features/partner-portal & http://www.mashery.com/product/features/api-packager

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is called API Management and there are a number of solutions.

## Integrated Billing - FOSS

Solutions that offer integrated billing that are Open Source, free, or charge a percentage (based on subscriptions, so no up-front fees):

- [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager)
- [3Scale](http://www.3scale.net/)
- [Apigee](http://apigee.com/) and [Apigee To-Go](http://apigee.com/docs/consoletogo)

## Integrated Billing - Commercial

Solutions that offer integrated billing, but charge for services:

- [Agilis Software](http://www.agilis-sw.com/ActivationLandingPage.htm)
- Mashery ([Partner](http://www.mashery.com/product/features/partner-portal), [API](http://www.mashery.com/product/features/api-packager)) - Was $499/month; prices are now unlisted
- [WebServius](http://www.webservius.com/)
- [mashape](https://www.mashape.com/pricing) - 20% of earnings; custom prices may be possible
- [apiary.io](http://apiary.io/) - in beta
- [SOA Software Open](http://open.soa.com)
- [Cloud Security Platform](http://cloudsecurity.intel.com/)
- [Vordel API Server](http://www.vordel.com/)
- [SDK Bridge](http://sdkbridge.com/)

## Components

Various sites and software that offer partial solutions from which a complete solution can be created.

### API Management

- [API Axle](http://apiaxle.com/)
- [Varnish API Key](https://code.google.com/p/varnish-apikey/)
- [apiGrove](http://apigrove.github.com/apigrove/)

### Accounts

- [DailyCred](https://www.dailycred.com/) - for accounts

### Documentation

- [SaaS Pose](http://saaspose.com/) - for API documentation

### Billing

- [Stripe](http://www.stripe.com/)
- [FastSpring](http://www.fastspring.com/)